# Search by datagridview1 column1 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

i using this code to search by textbox to get the related data for the ID

```
Dim connetionString As String
Dim cnn As SqlConnection
connetionString="DataSource=IP;InitialCatalog=DB;UserID=sa;Password=password"

cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

Dim com As String = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, cnn)

Dim ds As New DataSet()

Adpt.Fill(ds, "Table")

DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

What iam trying to do, i need to do the same code but with datagridview column1

Explaining:
i've already add button to upload data to datagridview the data include ID's
i need to search by those ID's in bulk, that included to the datagridview then post the income data to another datagridview,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves this type of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you should correct your existing code to use SQL Parameters.

```
Dim com As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID= @Id;", cnn)
com.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
```

Now to use the value in the first row, first column

```
Dim strId As String = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
Dim com2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID= @Id;", cnn)
com2.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strId
Dim Adpt2 As New SqlDataAdapter(com2)
```

I had to guess at the datatype. Please check your database to get the correct type. I guessed it was some type of string since you had it enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working fine now with this, i have only one question, i need to use the values in the first column values not the first row only,  how can i edit this code to do this? thanks in advance. @Mary

Comment: `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows` but you can't change the DataGridView while you are iterating. Save the values to something else and use them after the loop.